# Why does TPath.HasValidPathChars accept '?' as a valid char in a path?

Tags: delphi, path, directory, delphi-xe7

Why does System.IOUtils.TPath.HasValidPathChars accept'?' as a valid char in a path?
I set the second parameter (UseWildcards) to false. So, according to the documentation the '?' should be rejected. Still, the function returns True for 'c:\test\test?\'.

> UseWildcards = Specifies whether the mask characters are treated as
>   valid path characters (e.g. asterisk or question mark).

Is the behavior of this function only partially correct? Could the function have returned a better result?

Comment: The `?` should not be rejected because paths CAN contain question marks on Windows. Example: https://superuser.com/q/1069055

Comment: That superuser post also states: "You can't use these kinds of paths to access files or directories in userspace. Only certain low-level system components are designed to work with Object Manager paths." So from this viewpoint `?` is an invalid path character.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful - The article says that \?? is a valid path, so HasValidPathChars should check for '??' and return true IF the correct pattern ( \??) is found and false when there is a single '?'

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful `HasValidPathChars` recognises that with its use of `GetPosAfterExtendedPrefix`, but the rest of the function is hopelessly broken.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`TPath.HasValidPathChars` is completely broken. This is its implementation:

```
class function TPath.HasValidPathChars(const Path: string;
  const UseWildcards: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  PPath: PChar;
  PathLen: Integer;
  Ch: Char;
  I: Integer;
begin
  // Result will become True if an invalid path char is found
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  I := GetPosAfterExtendedPrefix(Path) - 1;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
  I := 0;
{$ENDIF POSIX}

  PPath := PChar(Path);
  PathLen := Length(Path);
  Result := False;

  while (not Result) and (i < PathLen) do
  begin
    Ch := PPath[i];
    if not IsValidPathChar(Ch) then
      if UseWildcards then
        if not IsPathWildcardChar(Ch) then
          Result := True
        else
          Inc(i)
      else
        Result := True
    else
      Inc(i);
  end;

  Result := not Result;
end;
```

The crucial point is the call to `IsValidPathChar`. Let's look at what that does.

```
class function TPath.IsValidPathChar(const AChar: Char): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not IsCharInOrderedArray(AChar, FInvalidPathChars);
end;
```

Now, `FInvalidPathChars` is defined to be:

```
FInvalidPathChars := TCharArray.Create(
  #0, #1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10, #11, #12,
  #13, #14, #15, #16, #17, #18, #19, #20, #21, #22, #23, #24,
  #25, #26, #27, #28, #29, #30, #31,
  '"', '<', '>', '|');            // DO NOT LOCALIZE;
```

That is, all ordinals less than 32, and `"`, `<`, `>` and `|`.

We also need to understand what `IsPathWildcardChar` does.

```
class function TPath.IsPathWildcardChar(const AChar: Char): Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsCharInOrderedArray(AChar, FPathWildcardChars);
end;
```

Where `FPathWildcardChars` is:

```
FPathWildcardChars := TCharArray.Create('*', '/', ':', '?', '\'); // DO NOT LOCALIZE;
```

Now, back to `TPath.HasValidPathChars`. Let's consider this `if` statement:

```
if not IsValidPathChar(Ch) then
```

The condition `not IsValidPathChar(Ch)` evaluates to `True` when `IsValidPathChar(Ch)` is `False`. Which happens if `Ch` is in `FInvalidPathChars`. That is if `Ch` has ordinal less than 32, or is one of `"`, `<`, `>` and `|`.

Your test string is `'C:\test\test?\'` and in fact none of these characters are in `FInvalidPathChars`. Which means that the condition in the `if not IsValidPathChar(Ch) then` statement always evaluates `False`. So even though your string contains a wildcard, it can never reach the subsequent test:

```
if UseWildcards then
```

It is easy to conclude that `HasValidPathChars` returns the same value irrespective of the value of the input parameter `UseWildcards`. And if you have any doubt about the analysis, this program should dispel it:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.IOUtils;

procedure Main;
var
  Ch: Char;
begin
  for Ch := low(Ch) to high(Ch) do
    if TPath.HasValidPathChars(Ch, False)<>TPath.HasValidPathChars(Ch, True) then
      Writeln('different at #' + IntToStr(ord(Ch)));
  Writeln('finished');
end;

begin
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

This looks like yet another function in this dreaded `IOUtils` unit that has been improperly implemented and not tested.

I have submitted a bug report: [RSP-18696](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-18696).

Based on having stumbled upon many such problems with `IOUtils`, my experience is that the unit is not to be trusted. I would not use it. Find an alternative way to solve your problem.

Comment: "It is easy to conclude that HasValidPathChars returns the same value irrespective of the value of the input parameter UseWildcards" - I just wanted to say exactly that!!!

Comment: Thanks David.       "my experience is that the unit is not to be trusted" - I had my own 'I/O utils' library but I replaced it with Embarcadero's when I purchased Delphi XE because... well... it was built by Embarcadero... so it must be better than mine... right? I am not top Delphi programmer so I expect that the worst programmer at Embarcadero to be at least 3 time better than me (he should be a TRUE Delphi professional, right?) !!!!!!!!!!!!!!   How they can let out such huge mistakes out? Probably this is why the IDE crashes so much: they used IOutils in their IDE code :)

Comment: @Edwin At least it is open. The defect that was hurting me yesterday was submitted 18 months ago and is still "reported".