# Get FileSystem Restrictions

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I would like to code a function that tells me if it's possible to WRITE a file/folder to a specific path or not. I would like to do that WITHOUT actually writing any file(s) to the disk. Is there a WINAPI function for that? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's no single function that will do that. If you can navigate the security API you can make a pretty good go at checking this in advance. By far the
easiest way to know whether or not you can write to some
location is to attempt to do so.

Comment: I've also dealt with this kind of situation. first I based my solution on checking ACL permissions, but soon I came to realize that the only reliable way is to actually try and create a temp file using `GetTempFileName` API (or whatever).

Comment: Well, i insert CD-ROM, then your program, checks ACL. You are granted the right to create your files - but the media just does not support it. Ditto for write-protected floppies, SD cards, etc. ACL is just not enough. Better try. Set Windows flags to auto-delete file on close, if you are afraid to live garbage in case of errors.

Comment: See also [How can I use Delphi to test if a Directory is writeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599256/how-can-i-use-delphi-to-test-if-a-directory-is-writeable)

Comment: @kobik I wanted to do the same but without writing a temporary file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [GetFileSecurity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [AccessCheck()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions. Read the  Aaron Ballman's article on [How to Check Access Rights](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2011/08/how-to-check-access-rights/). He provided the `CanAccessFolder()` function to do what you asked.

Answer (score 8):

```
function CheckFileAccess(const FileName: string; const CheckedAccess: Cardinal): Cardinal;
var Token: THandle;
    Status: LongBool;
    Access: Cardinal;
    SecDescSize: Cardinal;
    PrivSetSize: Cardinal;
    PrivSet: PRIVILEGE_SET;
    Mapping: GENERIC_MAPPING;
    SecDesc: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
begin
  Result := 0;
  GetFileSecurity(PChar(Filename), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, 0, SecDescSize);
  SecDesc := GetMemory(SecDescSize);

  if GetFileSecurity(PChar(Filename), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, SecDesc, SecDescSize, SecDescSize) then
  begin
    ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation);
    OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, False, Token);
    if Token <> 0 then
    begin
      Mapping.GenericRead := FILE_GENERIC_READ;
      Mapping.GenericWrite := FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
      Mapping.GenericExecute := FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
      Mapping.GenericAll := FILE_ALL_ACCESS;

      MapGenericMask(Access, Mapping);
      PrivSetSize := SizeOf(PrivSet);
      AccessCheck(SecDesc, Token, CheckedAccess, Mapping, PrivSet, PrivSetSize, Access, Status);
      CloseHandle(Token);
      if Status then
        Result := Access;
    end;
  end;

  FreeMem(SecDesc, SecDescSize);
end;
```

You use this like:
if (CheckFileAccess(SysteemGegevens.DFImportPath, FILE_ALL_ACCESS) <> FILE_ALL_ACCESS) then

with

```
const
FILE_READ_DATA = $0001;
FILE_WRITE_DATA = $0002;
FILE_APPEND_DATA = $0004;
FILE_READ_EA = $0008;
FILE_WRITE_EA = $0010;
FILE_EXECUTE = $0020;
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = $0080;
FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = $0100;
FILE_GENERIC_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ or FILE_READ_DATA or
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_READ_EA or SYNCHRONIZE);
FILE_GENERIC_WRITE = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE or FILE_WRITE_DATA or
FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_WRITE_EA or FILE_APPEND_DATA or SYNCHRONIZE);
FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE or FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or
FILE_EXECUTE or SYNCHRONIZE);
FILE_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED or SYNCHRONIZE or $1FF;
```

Comment: Could you explain what this function does, what are the input parameters and what is the result, please ? Btw., you should check results of the Windows API function calls...

Comment: This is seems to be the ported CanAccessFolder function from the answer above.

Comment: TLama: Sorry, added. Benjamin: I would not know, grabbed it from our code base

Comment: Hello, I used this function and started having printing related issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228886/function-to-get-permission-on-files-directories-causes-anomaly-in-functions-invo