# Function to get permission on files/directories causes anomaly in functions involving printer

Tags: delphi

I have the below function to check if a directory/file has access permission:

```
function CheckFileAccess(const FileName: string): Boolean;
const
  FILE_READ_DATA = $0001;
  FILE_WRITE_DATA = $0002;
  FILE_APPEND_DATA = $0004;
  FILE_READ_EA = $0008;
  FILE_WRITE_EA = $0010;
  FILE_EXECUTE = $0020;
  FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = $0080;
  FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = $0100;
  FILE_GENERIC_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ or FILE_READ_DATA or
    FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_READ_EA or SYNCHRONIZE);
  FILE_GENERIC_WRITE = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE or FILE_WRITE_DATA or
    FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES or FILE_WRITE_EA or FILE_APPEND_DATA or SYNCHRONIZE);
  FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE or FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES or
    FILE_EXECUTE or SYNCHRONIZE);
  FILE_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED or SYNCHRONIZE or $1FF;

var Token: THandle;
    Status: LongBool;
    Access: Cardinal;
    SecDescSize: Cardinal;
    PrivSetSize: Cardinal;
    PrivSet: PRIVILEGE_SET;
    Mapping: GENERIC_MAPPING;
    SecDesc: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
    CheckedAccess: Cardinal;
begin
try
  Result :=False;
  CheckedAccess:=FILE_ALL_ACCESS;
 try
  GetFileSecurity(PChar(Filename), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, 0, SecDescSize);
  SecDesc := GetMemory(SecDescSize);

  if GetFileSecurity(PChar(Filename), OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION or GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION or DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, SecDesc, SecDescSize, SecDescSize) then
  begin
    ImpersonateSelf(SecurityImpersonation);
    OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread, TOKEN_QUERY, False, Token);
    if Token <> 0 then
    begin
      Mapping.GenericRead := FILE_GENERIC_READ;
      Mapping.GenericWrite := FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
      Mapping.GenericExecute := FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
      Mapping.GenericAll := FILE_ALL_ACCESS;

      MapGenericMask(Access, Mapping);
      PrivSetSize := SizeOf(PrivSet);
      AccessCheck(SecDesc, Token, CheckedAccess, Mapping, PrivSet, PrivSetSize, Access, Status);
      CloseHandle(Token);
      if Status then
        Result := Access =  FILE_ALL_ACCESS;
    end;
  end;
 finally
   FreeMem(SecDesc, SecDescSize);
 end;
except
end;
end;
```

If after using this function, trying to execute any procedure where the printer is involved (from printing reports to PrintDialog1.Execute), it will raise exception "Operation not supported on selected printer".

I've reviewed the code several times, but I couldn't find any flaws that could be causing this error.
Including ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:=True; does not return any variables.

Comment: Since you do `except {nothing} end` you won't discover exceptions in your code, too - why doing that? Also: how is `SYNCHRONIZE` defined and which units do you use in which Delphi version?

Comment: Delphi 10.3, uses Winapi.Windows, Vcl.Forms;